# Trying to implement camera functionality with image_picker but keeps getting LateInitializationError [FLUTTER]

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have used stackoverflow for years but never bothered to register myself, but I feel the time has finally come. :)

I'm currently doing a school project in Flutter, which I'm very new to, and have now stumbled upon a problem. Have tried various things but I keep getting this exception:

> The following LateError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#9ab2f):
>
> > LateInitializationError: Field '_image@17109416' has not been initialized.

What could be causing this issue? Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';


void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
  // debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, // Turns off the 'DEBUG' sign in the upper right corner
));


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}


class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  // Camera implementation
  late File _image;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image!.path);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 90,
        title: const Text(
          'School project',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25.0,
            //fontFamily: '', // change the font?
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[600],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                  'Write or scan',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  )
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('write'); // test
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_rounded),
                label: const Text('Write'),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green[500]),
                  textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
                )
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
              _image == null ? Text("No Image Selected") : Image.file(_image),
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    getImage;
                    print('camera'); // test
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_rounded),
                  label: const Text('Scan'),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green[500]),
                    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
                  )
              )
            ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, should I try and change the position of the

> _image == null ? Text("No Image Selected") : Image.file(_image),

line somewhere more fitting or is it okay to have it nested like that? Do you have any other remarks on my code?

Comment: You cannot check if a `late` variable has been initialized.  If you need to perform such a check, it must be nullable instead.

Comment: Remove`late` keyword. Use ` File? _image`.

Comment: @JahidulIslam
I have tried to use 'File? _image;' instead, but then I get the following errors:

lib/main.dart:70:71: Error: The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File' because 'File?' is nullable and 'File' isn't.
 - 'File' is from 'dart:io'.
              _image == null ? Text("No Image Selected") : Image.file(_image),
                                                                      ^
lib/main.dart:21:9: Context: '_image' refers to a property so it couldn't be promoted.
  File? _image;
        ^

Comment: without null safe it working for me

Comment: @JahidulIslam I managed to solve the errors!  I added a '!' after _image and now it works.
_image == null ? Text("No Image Selected") : Image.file(_image!),

Comment: However, the camera won't start when I press on the Camera button in my app. What could be causing this issue?
onPressed: () {
                    getImage;
},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
 ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: getImage, // here need to change
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_rounded),
                  label: const Text('Scan'),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green[500]),
                    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
                  )
              )
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir! Now the camera opens.

I have two follow questions:
Do I really need the "_image == null ? Text("No Image Selected") : Image.file(_image!)," line if I just want to save the picture to a database?

Also, do you recommend MongoDB or Firebase?

Comment: it depends on your preference. It would be good to analysis your requirement.